# Unwanted wx.EVT_MENU event is being fired upon pressing return key

Tags: python, events, menu, wxpython

In this code EVT_MENU is being fired for enter key but shortcut is not defined in menus.

```
import wx

class Interface(wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Testwin", size=(300, 300))
        self.CenterOnScreen()

        self.SetMenus()

        # Ignore default sizer that stretches lonely panel to cover everything
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(100, 100), pos=(100, 100))
        panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        self.Show()
        self.Raise()

    def SetMenus (self):
        m = wx.Menu()
        m.Append(100, "E&xit\tAlt+F4")
        mb = wx.MenuBar()
        mb.Append(m, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(mb)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.MenuManager)

    def MenuManager (self, e):
        id = e.GetId()
        print id
        if id==100: self.Close()

app = wx.App()
i = Interface()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is happening on Win XP Pro SP3.

The ID of the fired event when enter is pressed is 1.
Can I safely use this fact to process or ignore the event in question?

Why is this happening at all? I didn't define it anywhere.

Can I somehow remove enter as a shortcut from acceleration table if it is there for some reason?

Comment: yeah, I've never noticed this behavior before. It goes away if you bind to specific menu ids. Windows 10, wx 4.0.2

Comment: Yes I know, but I need and want to use this way. I have dynamic menu creation in my real program and too many bindings and then unbindings will make mess of the code.